# questions on header in MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, header, mime

In an MVC framework, responsible for defining the header would be the controller or view?

Imagining a situation to download a file, there would be rendering the content, so I imagine that the controller would set the appropriate header to download, correct?

Another point is that I have doubts regarding the mimes ...
by default we use `text / html; charset = UTF-8,` the other would be to set the mime type of file to download, is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Correct, controller should "decide" which is the appropriate header
2. Content-type is the header you want to change.

Comment: the controller's responsibility is to handle input, not to decide on output

Comment: @Gordon : I usually agree with you (silently) but, here, I think that's wrong. Take j2ee for example. Controller got responsibility of "request" and "response". It doesn't control what's *inside* the view but it controls *what* is going out (headers mainly). In many PHP framework, it's also the case (symfony, for example)

Comment: you say that it controls the application, and is a request and sets the status 200 (ok) or 404 (not found).
in which case he receives the content and sends the view for rendering, right?

Comment: @Shikiryu Yes and No. It's true that it's common practise to have the controllers create the response in *web-based* MVC frameworks. It's an implementation detail though. There is no notion of protocol or delivery mechanism in MVC. It just says "splits user interaction into three distinct roles" (at least if you follow the POEAA definition). So by definition, HTTP Request and HTTP Response are not part of the MVC problem domain.

Comment: @Gordon I agree with that. It's nice to follow definitions and specifications when it applies). But we're developping web applications. If definitions doesn't take what you need into account, you need to do it yourself. That's what all web-based "MVC"   has done. Even without them, we need to take request and response into account. Personnaly, I'm used to manage headers in the controller (or via the controller, `$this->view->setHeader()` for example. You change the view but *in* the controller) and I still find it logical.

Comment: @Shikiryu well yes, but you could also handle all HTTP related stuff outside the context of MVC or have the View decide on the resource representation by injecting the HTTP Request and then let the View decide whether to return XML, JSON or HTML or whatever. That's what I mean by it boils down to implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

All the presentation logic is responsibility of View instances. This would apply even if you are using MVP pattern, where view is a passive entity view ("passive" does not mean "dumb" or "just template").

Controller should be responsible for only changing the state of model layer and current view.

Comment: if I have a request for download, I have a view only to set the header type?

Comment: Yes. It asks the model layer for file details, and depending on response, it generates either an error page or initiated download.

Comment: so to finish the question ... then to render a complete page, use "text / html" and the rest of mimes used to download, it's correct? obrigado

Comment: @PapaCharlie and in some cases you will also send the redirect header, or maybe mime type for json response.